# Overriding Exception.Message / exception pattern matching

Tags: exception, f#, pattern-matching

I'm trying to pattern match on an exception within its definition. Is something like the following possible using F#'s exception syntax, or must I subclass `Exception`?

This is what I expected to work:

```
exception CoordErr of int * int
    with
        override this.Message = 
            let CoordErr(x, y) = this
            sprintf "(%i %i)" x y //ERROR
```

But yields the errors:

> The value or constructor 'x' is not defined
>   The value or constructor 'y' is not defined

**EDIT**

I also tried adding parens:

```
let (CoordErr(x, y)) = this
```

But this gives the error:

> This expression was expected to have type exn but here has type CoordErr

**UPDATE**

The following works, but isn't ideal:

```
exception CoordErr of int * int
    with
        override this.Message = 
            sprintf "(%i %i)" this.Data0 this.Data1
```

Is there another way to do this?

**UPDATE 2**

Taking a cue from kvb's answer, I suppose I could do the following to swallow the `incomplete matches` warning:

```
exception CoordErr of int * int
    with
        override this.Message = 
            match this :> exn with
            | CoordErr(x, y) -> sprintf "(%i %i)" x y
            | _ -> Unchecked.defaultof<_>
```

Comment: I'd change it from `Unchecked.defaultof<_>` to `failwith "impossible"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first attempt doesn't work because you're defining a let-bound function called `CoordErr` which shadows the exception constructor, which isn't what you want.

Your second attempt almost works.  Unfortunately, exception definitions don't work quite like discriminated unions: when pattern matching against an exception constructor, the expression that you're matching has to be of type `exn` (and not of the specific exception subtype).  In your case, you are trying to match `this` (of type `CoordErr`) against the `CoordErr` constructor.  How's this for a workaround?

```
exception CoordErr of int * int
    with
        override this.Message = 
          let (CoordErr(x,y)) = upcast this
          sprintf "(%i %i)" x y
```

Comment: It's great (the `incomplete pattern matches` warning is a minor annoyance, but oh well). Can you explain the need for the upcast?

Comment: Nevermind. You were apparently explaining it as I was asking. :)

Comment: @kvb - I updated the question with code that avoids the warning. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @Daniel - I agree that the behavior is a bit weird (and very subtle).  In a way, it does seem consistent, though: `let e = CoordErr(1,2)` results in `e` having static type `exn`, not `CoordErr`, so it makes sense that `CoordErr` is used to destruct `exn` values when used as a pattern, too.

Comment: @kvb - I didn't realize that. Very good to know. In light of that it makes sense.

Comment: @Daniel - I'd use `#nowarn "25"` instead, since you know that the pattern will always match in this case.

Comment: @kvb - I suppose this should ideally be in a file of its own, since `#nowarn` applies to the entire file.

Comment: @kvb - Thanks for your answer -- insightful as usual.

Answer (score 2):

Naming the constructor arguments and accessing the corresponding fields seems to work:

```
exception CoordErr of x : int * y : int
    with
        override this.Message = 
            sprintf "(%i %i)" this.x this.y
```

I realise this is not a pattern-matching solution, but it does answer the "Overriding Exception.Message" part of your question. :)

Comment: This is probably the cleanest solution, but named union fields hadn't yet been added to F# when I asked the question.

Comment: Understood, just added this for future visitors :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the exception aware pattern matching of a try with expression

```
exception CoordErr of int * int
    with
        override this.Message = 
            try raise this with CoordErr(x, y) -> sprintf "(%i %i)" x y
```

Comment: This is far from ideal, as raising and catching takes far more time than regular operations. Even if it is only done once, it is a very bad habit.

Comment: That said, If it's happening often enough for performance to be a concern, it's not a condition exceptional enough that it should be represented as an exception. Rather, use Result or a custom DU.